# Async try-catch-wait one second block?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I still can't quite exactly understand async/await methods and threading and what's exactly the difference, but i'm trying to work with them so I can better understand them, so be warned everything i'm doing might be fundementaly wrong.
I have a console application that works as a server, first it makes an HttpListener object and invokes BeginGetContext, and everytime the callback function executes, it starts another BeginGetContext. On the other hand in the main thread(i think), I read commands given to the console and execute it in the main thread.
Now I store my data in a dictionary, which I can, using these commands, serialize and deserialize. I thought at some point another running c# app is going to use this serialized data to like process to make statistics or whatever. I thought if one program is reading this data while the other tries to also read it, it's gonna throw some exception and ruin the flow of the program and become a mess of copies. So I thought about making these try-catch checks everytime I want to get data from either program:

```cs
static bool IsFileAvailable(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;
    try { stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open); }
    catch (IOException) { return false; }
    finally { if (stream != null) stream.Close(); }
    return true;
}
```

In the main thread, i test, if file IsFileAvailable, I get the file, otherwise, I want the main thread to continue executing while some method (asynchronously I guess) tests if IsFileAvailable every second or so, before giving up after maybe 30 seconds and leaving a message to the console. I don't exactly know what method to use in order to keep both the main thread and the HttpListener requests running. Should I actually start a thread and close it to get the file to open ? Am I maybe doing everything entirly wrong ? Also if async functions run on seperate threads, shouldn't the program run out of threads at some point ?
Thanks in advance and apologies for the long question.

Comment: Posting some code would be a lot more useful than describing the code.

Comment: `if async functions run on seperate threads` - They don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I still can't quite exactly understand async/await methods

Async is just a keyword that mark a method as asynchronous. By default, when an incomplete Task is awaited, the current “context” is captured and used to resume the method when the Task completes. This “context” is the current SynchronizationContext unless it’s null, in which case it’s the current TaskScheduler.

> I thought if one program is reading this data while the other tries to also read it, it's gonna throw some exception and ruin the flow of the program and become a mess of copies.

Data Reading by multiple threads dosn't cause error while data is not null and you don't try to change data at the same time.
The code you have written, blocks the main thread at all. If you plan on making this method async, you should start a task asynchronous and call it in your main thread as follows:

```
private static async Task<bool> IsFileAvailable(FileInfo file)
    {
        //Your Code
    }
public static async Task DoStuff()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            LongRunningOperation();
        });   
    }
static void Main()
    {
       DoStuff();
       //Other Codes
    }
```

But because this call is not awaited, execution of the main method continues before the task is completed. Note that you can't await it in Main(), because it is a console app and the Main method can not be awaited at all.